# Is there a way to create more than one ElasticSearch index with a single query

Tags: elasticsearch

Following the [create index docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-create-index.html) I know how to create a index with custom settings, i.e.

```
PUT /my-new-index
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 2 
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to initialise more than one index at a time, all with the same settings? I'm looking at something like the [delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-delete-index.html), which allows for a query of the form

```
DELETE /index1,index2,index3
```

to delete more than one index at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index template` API to use the same settings among other indices.

`Create index` API does not support multiple indices creations.

[Put index template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

> Index templates define settings and mappings that you can automatically apply when creating new indices. Elasticsearch applies templates to new indices based on an index pattern that matches the index name.

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards" : 3, 
    "number_of_replicas" : 2 
  }
}
```

Then create an index

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get index settings `GET my_index/_settings`

```
{

"my_index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1575300164818",
        "number_of_shards" : "3",
        "number_of_replicas" : "2",
        "uuid" : "SfRWgW96RX2a0rRYNtdodA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7040199"
        },
        "provided_name" : "my_index"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See `number_of_shards` and `number_of_replicas` in results.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Dani Medina is that what you were looking for?